# 3D Mapping packages for Velodyne VLP-16 Lidars

Tags: ros, octomap, vlp-16, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have to create a 3D map using the point clouds from Velodyne VLP-16 lidar. I found two packages namely, ethzasl_icp_mapper (http://wiki.ros.org/ethzasl_icp_mapper) and octomap (http://wiki.ros.org/octomap). Are there any other packages that support VLP-16 apart from these? The ethzasl_icp_mapper and the octomap ROS wiki do not describe the procedure to use the library in detail. I read some more posts in this forum regarding the use of the ethzasl library. But, none of them seem to talk about the steps to to be followed to get the map. Since, I'm new to ROS, I am finding it a bit difficult to understand. This is what I understood from the wiki;

1. After installing & compiling the mapping stack, I have to launch the VLP-16 launch file .
2. I have to publish the pointcloud2 messages from the lidar to /cloud_in node.
3. After registering the clouds, the package publishes the output map in /point_map node and the odometry in the /icp_odom node.

Here are some of the questions I have;

1. Where can I find the VLP-16 launch file?
2. Should I do the sensor to odom and then to map frame transformations manually?
3. How do I input odometry info? Can I create a map without odometry?

It would be really helpful if someone can describe the sequence of steps to be done to use this library.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227804/3d-mapping-packages-for-velodyne-vlp-16-lidars/) by [krishnaece1505](https://answers.ros.org/users/25947/krishnaece1505/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2016-02-29

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can only answer your first question:

To use a VLP-16, you currently have to [build the velodyne driver from source](http://answers.ros.org/question/226594/how-do-i-build-ros-vlp16-velodyne-driver-for-indigo-using-catkin/). That is because the Indigo version was released *before* VLP-16 support was added. (A new release is planned, but not yet done.)

The launch file you need is included in the [velodyne_pointcloud](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne_pointcloud) package:

```
$ roslaunch velodyne_pointclound VLP16_points.launch
```

Your other questions are not really specific to Velodyne, they would apply to 3D SLAM using any sensor that produces a point cloud.

I am sure others know more than I do about all that. I am interested in those answers, too.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-02-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [krishnaece1505](https://answers.ros.org/users/25947/krishnaece1505/) on 2016-02-29**:
I didn't know that this is the same launch file as the one that comes with the velodyne driver. Thank you for the info anyways. Even I am curious to know how to get started with 3D SLAM using velodyne. Hoping someone would make it clear:)